# HTML form fields - validate OR allow blank

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I have a HTML form created using `Codeigniter` and `PHP`, I am trying to set validation on 2 fields. The fields can be left blank, but if one is populated and not the other, an error should be generated. The fields are:

-ltitle[]
-llink[]    `//array of multiple links corresponding to ltitle[]`

I am trying to implement validation ONLY if either one of the fields are populated.

```
     if(  !empty($_POST['ltitle']) || !empty($_POST['llink']) ) 
     {
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('ltitle[]', 'ltitle', 'xss_clean|callback_check_link');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('llink[]', 'llink', 'xss_clean|callback_check_link'); 
     }
```

check_link function:

```
function check_link($ltitle){

    $llink = $_POST['llink'];
    if(empty($ltitle) && empty($llink) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    elseif(  (empty($ltitle) && !empty($llink) ) || (!empty($ltitle) && empty($llink) )  )
        {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_link', 'Complete the link fields correctly');
        return false;
        }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

At the moment when the form is submitted with both fields blank, the error message displays 'Complete the link fields correctly', meaning check_link function has executed. But the fields are empty??  ! Would really appreciate help on this!

Comment: Why have you added `$llink = $_POST['llink'];` but not `$ltitle= $_POST['ltitle'];` ? Your callback function seems like it would work as expected while checking `$ltitle` but not when checking `$llink`.

Comment: change this `if(  !empty($_POST['ltitle']) && !empty($_POST['ltitle']) )`

Comment: I have changed check_link:
"function check_link(){
        
        $ltitle = $_POST['ltitle'];
        $llink = $_POST['ltitle'];
        
        if(  (empty($ltitle) && !empty($llink) ) || (!empty($ltitle) && empty($llink) )  )
            {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_link', 'Complete the link fields correctly');
            return false;
            }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }    
    } "

which now allows blanks to be submitted. But its not throwing the error when only one field is filled?

Answer (score 0):

Might be several factors contributing to the problem. First, I would not set the rules a conditionally. Second, because the validation callback will be run twice, once for each field, set the message in the controller. Otherwise it potentially gets set twice which is extra processing that's not needed.

Change this

```
 if(  !empty($_POST['ltitle']) || !empty($_POST['ltitle']) ) 
 {
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('ltitle[]', 'ltitle', 'xss_clean|callback_check_link');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('llink[]', 'llink', 'xss_clean|callback_check_link'); 
 }
```

to this

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('ltitle[]', 'ltitle', 'xss_clean|callback_check_link');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('llink[]', 'llink', 'xss_clean|callback_check_link'); 
 $this->form_validation->set_message('check_link', 'Complete the link fields correctly');
```

The same callback is used for each field which means the parameter passed is the value of the field being checked. You retrieve `$_POST['llink']` but that will be the passed parameter in one case. You should retrieve both explicitly and ignore the param. Also, the logic can be much simplified.

```
function check_link($ltitle)
{
    //use trim() to make sure the value isn't a string of one (or more) space characters
    $is_llink = !empty(trim($_POST['llink']));
    $is_ltitle = !empty(trim($_POST['ltitle']));
    return ($is_llink && $is_ltitle) || (!$is_llink && !$is_ltitle);
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Actually the final line in the callback can be even more simple.

Change

```
return ($is_llink && $is_ltitle) || (!$is_llink && !$is_ltitle);
```

to

```
return $is_llink === $is_ltitle;
```

**EDIT 2**

Even more simple. Don't set a rule for both fields. This eliminates the need to get both `$_POST` items because one is passed to the callback.

In the controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ltitle[]', 'ltitle', 'xss_clean|callback_check_link');
$this->form_validation->set_message('check_link', 'Complete the link fields correctly');
```

Then the callback becomes

```
function check_link($ltitle)
{
    return empty(trim($ltitle)) === empty(trim($_POST['llink']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In code igniter $_POST[""] = $this->input->post("")

```
//Set the values not to null, but to an empty variable
$llink = "";
$ltitle = "";
if ( $this->input->post("ltitle") = $ltitle AND $this->input->post("llink ") = $llink ) 
//If the inputs have an empty value
{

} 
//Make sure they are both set, and populated
else if ( !empty($this->input->post("ltitle")) AND !empty($this->input->post("llink ")) 
//If they are both set, then check their values
{
   //Title doesn't need a link check i think
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('ltitle[]', 'ltitle', 'xss_clean');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('llink[]', 'llink', 'xss_clean|callback_check_link'); 
   //Run the validation procces
   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_link', 'Complete the link fields correctly');
    }
    else
    {
      $this->load->view('formsuccess');
    }
 }
```

And make sure your callbacks (**callback_check_link**) are valid and do check for for link validity.